# Can someone explain the relationship between apex, objects, and soql?,

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, app

Ok so, I am trying to perform certain calculations in Salesforce but I am pretty new to the whole thing.

What I eventually am trying to do is: Access the certain values from Opportunities and Companies, and then perform calculations by month across each of those, and ultimately create a report based on those calculations.

From what I understand, I am going to have to create an app, which has objects, which pull data from Opportunities or Companies using SOQL. The SOQL is within an Apex Class that will operate on an apex trigger.

Once those objects are created in the new app, I can then create a report based on those objects.

Does this sound somewhat accurate? I am a little confused on the relationship between a custom object and an existing object, as well as how apex relates between the two.

Comment: Hi Garrett, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. This question is just way to broad to answer here. You should work through some [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) modules first to gain a broader understanding of the platform.

Comment: Ok, sorry I do realize it was a broad question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GarrettMiller if you use standard Salesforce objects (sObjects), the objects are already created for you. While a standard "company" object isn't available, the Account object may be the object you'd want to use. What you need to do is create records from each object to use in your reports, and use SOQL to query for the specific record you want to change in your trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As Adrian has correctly suggested Trailhead is way to start to understand Salesforce platform.

Here are some pointers on Apex, Objects and SOQL.

[Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm):

> Apex is a strongly typed, object-oriented programming language that
>   allows developers to execute flow and transaction control statements
>   on the Force.com platform server in conjunction with calls to the
>   Force.com​ API. Using syntax that looks like Java and acts like
>   database stored procedures, Apex enables developers to add business
>   logic to most system events, including button clicks, related record
>   updates, and Visualforce pages.

[Object](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/data_modeling/objects_intro):

> A record is analogous to a row in a database table. Objects already
>   created for you by Salesforce are called standard objects. Objects you
>   create in your organization are called custom objects. Objects you
>   create that map to data stored outside your organization are called
>   external objects.

[SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm):

> Use the Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL) to search your
>   organization’s Salesforce data for specific information. SOQL is
>   similar to the SELECT statement in the widely used Structured Query
>   Language (SQL) but is designed specifically for Salesforce data.

Example:

```
public class DemoClass {

    // Constructor
    public DemoClass(){
        List<Account> accountList = [Select Id, Name from Account limit 100]; // SOQL to retrieve 100 account records from Object Account
    }
}
```